# SQLITE3 Query COUNT and ORDER BY

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a basic table that I'd like some help parsing out some data from.

Right now I run two queries to get the data I want.

Query 1 (for total count or 'number' of tally_id's)

```
SELECT
 count(*)
FROM
 tally
WHERE
time >= '2019-02-25 00:00' AND time <= '2019-03-04 21:00';
```

In this example above I get my result which is 247

Query 2

```
SELECT
 tally_id,
 count(*)
FROM
 tally
WHERE
time >= '2019-02-25 00:00' AND time <= '2019-03-04 21:00'
GROUP BY
 tally_id;
```

This gives me the count totals for each of the 'tally_id's such as

```
Orange Blocks|5
Red Blocks|5
Yellow Blocks|10
Tan Blocks|11
Blue Blocks|12
Purple Blocks|24
Black Blocks|121
Green Blocks|59
```

Is there a way to combine both so it was one nice seamless query operation?  I'd like to see the total number of blocks, as in 247 above as well as a total for each individual type of block.

Thanks interwebz!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `union` to combine your two queries

```
SELECT tally_id,count(*)
FROM tally
WHERE time >= '2019-02-25 00:00' AND time <= '2019-03-04 21:00'
GROUP BY tally_id
union
SELECT 'total', count(*)
FROM tally
WHERE time >= '2019-02-25 00:00' AND time <= '2019-03-04 21:00'
```

Comment: Perfect!  That was exactly what I was looking for thank you!

Comment: Another question.  How would I go about setting up the query to parse out the day by day totals as in the above example there are counts and data for the individual days between WHERE time >= '2019-02-25 00:00' AND time <= '2019-03-04 21:00' ?

Comment: convert time to date and and this is select list as well as group by @tengoindiamike